# Converting ["1, 2, 3"] to [1, 2, 3], in python?

Tags: python

I tried:

```
my_list = ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"]

new_list = []

for e in my_list:
    for sub_e in e:
        new_list.append(int(sub_e))
```

But I think it is iterating over `1,`, `2,`, etc... How would one convert `["1, 2, 3"]` to a list of integers `[1, 2, 3]`?

My desired output is a list of integers: [1, 2, 3]

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
my_list = ["1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"]

new_list = []

for e in my_list:
    for sub_e in e.split(","):
        new_list.append(int(sub_e))
```

Comment: Taking notice of just the 0th element, what we are doing is: `my_list[0].split(",")`. If I print this, I get `["1", "2", "3"]`. Why wouldn't it be `["1,", "2," , "3,"]` given each element in `"1, 2, 3"` is `1,`

Comment: Or a dirty one-liner: `list(map(int, sum(list(map(lambda x: x.split(','), my_list)), [])))`

Comment: I prefer this one: `[ int(i) for i in ','.join(my_list).split(',') ]`

Comment: @user3138766: try `my_list[0].split(" ")`, the `split` method doesn't keep the separator string in the pieces, (then the separator is a space, which I don't think is correct)

Comment: My favorite one liner is : `new_list = [int(sub_e) for e in my_list for sub_e in e.split(',')]`